# Получить из строки только уникальные элементы

Tags: java, строки, arraylist

Стоит задача, получить из строки только уникальные элементы, все дублируещиеся элементы необходимо удалить. Пример:

```
Input:
String line = "Однажды в стране и однажды в мире";
Output:
"стране и мире"
```

Во первых я получаю массив слов

```
String[] words = str.replaceAll("[^\\da-zA-Za-яёА-ЯЁ ]", "").toLowerCase().split(" ");
```

Затем мне надо пройти по этому массиву и сравнить первый элемент с последующими и если нахожу повтор, то беру следующий элемент и если он не повторяется, то ложу его в список `List<String> uniqueWords = new ArrayList<>()`
Написал так:

```
for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    String temp = words[i];
    for (int j = 0; j < uniqueWords.size(); j++) {
        if (uniqueWords.get(j).equals(temp)){
            break;
        } else {
             uniqueWords.add(temp);
           }
      }
  }

for(String cell : uniqueWords){
    result.append(cell).append(" ");
 }
System.out.println(result);
```

Но это не работает. Что-то упускаю и делаю не правильно, а разобраться не могу.Хотелось бы сделать это без использования `Map`
Прошу помощи в данном вопросе.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы сразу кладёте слово, если первая же проверка удаётся, а нужно выждать до конца. И сравнивать не с отобранными уникальными, а с остатком массива.(Флаг сделайте булевским, как там оно у вас в Java записывается)

```
for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    String temp = words[i];
    int flag = 1;  
    for (int j = 0; j < words.length; j++) {
        if ((i!=j) && (words.get(j).equals(temp))){
            flag = 0;
            break;
        }
      }
   if (flag==1) {
       uniqueWords.add(temp);
   }
  }
```

Comment: Отметил ответ MBo так, как он был первым. Спасибо за подсказку, я действительно не учитывал, что надо идти до конца и сравнивать с остатком массива.

Answer (score 2):

Такая задача стандартно решается построением мапы частот слов `Map<String, Integer>` и последующей фильтрацией по частоте слова, не превышающей 1.  Это позволяет решить её без квадратичного поиска, со сложностью O(N).

Кроме того, для получения массива слов излишним будет применение replaceAll, достаточно будет разбить строку по символам, не являющимся буквами или цифрами `[^\p{L}\p{N}]`

```java
String[] words = str.toLowerCase().split("[^\\p{L}\\p{N}]+");
```

Для построения мапы удобно использовать Stream API:

```java
List<String> uniqueWords = Arrays.stream(words)
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        w -> w, LinkedHashMap::new, Collectors.counting()
    )) // Map<String, Long>
    .entrySet()
    .stream() // Stream<Map.Entry<String, Long>>
    .filter(e -> 1L == e.getValue())
    .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(uniqueWords);
System.out.println(String.join(" ", uniqueWords));
```

Вывод:

```java
[стране, и, мире]
стране и мире
```

---

Без применения мап и вычисления частоты можно использовать два `Set` -- первый будет регистрировать все вхождения, а второй -- только дубликаты, используя факт, что метод `Set::add` возвращает `false`, если элемент уже существует в данном сете, после завершения основного цикла из первого сета следует удалить все обнаруженные дубликаты при помощи `Set::removeAll`.

Здесь также будет сложность O(N).

```java
Set<String> uniques = new LinkedHashSet<>();
Set<String> dups = new HashSet<>();
for (String word : words) {
    if (!uniques.add(word)) {
        dups.add(word);
    }
}
uniques.removeAll(dups);
System.out.println(uniques);
System.out.println(String.join(" ", uniques));
```

Вывод:

```
[стране, и, мире]
стране и мире
```

Использовав `Set<String> uniques = new TreeSet<>();` можно отсортировать слова по алфавиту.

---

Также можно несколько оптимизировать существующее решение, если устанавливать слова-дубликаты в `null` при итерации по массиву `words`, в лучшем случае (все дубликаты) будет сложность O(N), в худшем (ни одного дубликата) квадратичная сложность сохранится, но реально количество итераций составит `n * (n - 1) / 2`:

```java
for (int i = 0, n = words.length; i < n; i++) {
    String word = words[i];
    if (null == word) {
        continue; // обнаружен удалённый дубликат
    }
    boolean unique = true;
    for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {
        if (word.equals(words[j])) {
            unique = false;
            words[j] = null;
        }
    }
    if (unique) {
        uniqueWords.add(word);
    }
}
System.out.println(uniqueWords);
```

Comment: Alex Rudenko, Это уже высший пилотаж ))) Спасибо, буду углубляться в изучение коллекций и стримов

Comment: Alex Rudenko, отличная логика, как я не додумался до такого ... метод `add` возвращает `false` если слово не помещается в `Set`, значит оно дубликат и его надо положить в список дубликатов, а потом просто вывести этот список в консоль. Супер. Как научиться находить разные варианты решения ??

Answer (score 1):

Исходя из Вашего ТЗ, могу предложить Вам следующий код

```
        String line = "Однажды в стране и однажды в мире";
        String[] words = line.replaceAll("[^\\da-zA-Za-яёА-ЯЁ ]", "").toLowerCase().split(" ");
        List<String> wordList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String word : words) {
            int count = 0;
            for (String s : words) {
                if (word.equalsIgnoreCase(s))
                    count++;
            }
            if (count == 1)
                wordList.add(word);
        }
        System.out.println(wordList);
```

Comment: Ваш ответ тоже очень полезен, но я уже отметил верное решение.
А `word.equalsIgnoreCase(s)` можно не делать, я же уже перевел все символы в нижний регистр

Comment: @YuriiS Решение помечается галочкой, а плюсики можно хоть всем ставить.

Comment: MBo, поставил ))